# django - multiple payment choice (including paypal) in the same page, possible implementations

Tags: python, django, paypal

In a site I'm developing, I need to set up a payment system, which includes paypal and simple bank transfers (I basically send an email to the user with the bank account's info, nothing fancy).

What I want to achieve is to have both methods in the same page, selectable with radio buttons: if paypal is selected, the user is redirected to the paypal site, while if bank transfer is selected a success view is rendered after the email has been sent.

I'm well aware of the existence of django-paypal to integrate paypal into django. Only problem is, it relies on its own form to do that, and this doesn't really comply with my use case.

So what I want to ask is how would you tackle the problem, here's a couple of ideas I had:

- Have two buttons instead of two radio buttons (means two forms in the same page, the one django-paypal is shipped with and another for the bank transfers)
- Keep the radio buttons and use javascript to generate the payment form (although I'm not sure there would be security issues by doing so).

How do you think I could solve the problem? Are my ideas okay, which one is the best, are there better solutions I can consider?

Comment: you could use this: https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python and manage all the client side stuff yourself directly.

Comment: I read a little about this api. Thing is, I need to handle IPNs, and I think it's got no support for that. Could also be that I misread, though.

Comment: Mmm, looks like using the sdk is the way to go, I will stick to your idea. Thanks for the hint.